# How to upload the newly created to github?

Tags: codeigniter, github

I have one project developed using codeigniter and pulled from github.

In that I created one new folder called media in the root path of Codeigniter.

How to upload that folder to github?

Can I upload the folder like other files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "git add" your new folder so it can be tracked by git and uploaded with the other files.

```
git add <path to the media folder>
git commit -a -m 'Added media folder'
git push <repository> <branch>
```

If you need more explanations about how git works, you can look [here](http://git-scm.com/book)

Comment: while uploading the folder by using git add command , all the files present in the folder are automatically uploaded into github?

Comment: I think so. You can check if all the files you want are tracked by running 'git status' command. If there is no untracked files mentioned, then you're ok.

Comment: @SwathiS, Git doesn't track directories at all; it tracks the content of files. If you `git add` a directory, its files are added and tracked. The directory is only "tracked" in the sense that it is a container for its files. You can see this by trying to add an empty directory.

Comment: Yep, forgot to say that, thanks Chris.
If you add new files in your media folder, they won't be automagically tracked by git, you have to `git add` them as it only tracks files. (`git add` on a folder is a shortcut to add all files inside this folder)